# RadTreeViewItem, MVVM, and Click events

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, telerik, eventtrigger, rad-controls

I'm having trouble getting a click event or mouse down event to fire on a RadTreeViewItem in the ViewModel. What syntax should I be using? This is the relevant XAML below:

```
            <Toolkit:AccordionItem x:Name="Accordion1" Header="{Binding Header, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200">
            <ListBox x:Name="SitesList" Width="195" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Games, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadTreeView IsDragDropEnabled="True" IsSingleExpandPath="True"  
                                             telerikDragDrop:RadDragAndDropManager.AllowDrag="True" PreviewDragEnded="RadTreeView_PreviewDragEnded"
                                             IsDragTooltipEnabled="False">
                            <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="{Binding siteName, Mode=TwoWay}" Tag="{Binding siteKey, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RadTreeItemClickCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </telerik:RadTreeViewItem>
                        </telerik:RadTreeView>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
        </Toolkit:AccordionItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, binding the events of the RadTreeViewItem has to be done in code-behind; the ItemPrepared event of RadTreeView is fired when a RadTreeViewItem is created and bindings can be set in a handler. More information here:

http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreeview-events-working-with-item-prepared-event.html

Answer (score -1):

Don't bother with the event to command.  You can set a command on the RadTreeViewItem directly.